# NPM default registry config to a private repo doesn't work

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, azure-devops

On my local MacOs, I have set registry npm config to `https://<myrepo>.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/<myrepo>/npm/registry/` in both the project directory `.npmrc` beside `package.json` and also in `$HOME\.nmprc`.
But still, when I run `npm i` it doesn't replace `https://registry.npmjs.org` with the one configured above.
What else I am missing to config?

**EDIT:**
I realized that the problem is with dependency packages.

Comment: Thanks @Kevin,  I didn't try further yet but will update here.

Comment: Feel free to let me know the result. If you have any questions, I  will still be here to help you.

Answer (score 1):

When I put .npmrc file in the same directory as package.json, running npm install will use the registry in npmrc.

[image]

You need to check if the **package-lock.json file** was generated during your previous npm install.

If yes, you could **remove** this file and run the npm install again.

Here is a doc about [Package-lock.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-lock-json).  And the doc about c[onfigure the .npmrc on Mac/linux machine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/npm/npmrc?view=azure-devops&tabs=windows#linux-or-mac)

On the other hand, you can also try to use the following command to set the registry:

```
npm config set registry feedurl
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin, my registery feed url is set fine, it is not the problem.

Comment: Also, fyi, I removed `package-lock.json file` and then ran `npm install` and it didn't help.

Comment: Also, I had followed `configure the .npmrc on Mac/linux machine` doc you mentioned exactly and it is working for some package but strangely not all!